# MacBook Air M1, Podcasts Bug?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, apple-silicon, podcasts.app

My podcasts do not sync between my MacBook Air M1 and my iPhone 11 Pro Max. Furthermore, when I bring up the iOS Podcast App from my iPhone using Handoff and click on it on my Mac, I get an error message “Podcast not Available You are not following [some random date] on this device". I am signed in on the same iCloud account and all software is up to date. Everything else on iCloud seems to sync fine. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Have you tried signing out and signing back in on the Podcast app on your MacBook?

Comment: Wow! It never occurred to me to sign in! I now see the “account” drop down menu. Thank you for your reply.